# Clear interval in React class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, clearinterval

So, we have this simple React component that receives an integer from the father component. When the button is clicked, we display the integer on the screen and the countdown begins.

The question is how can I stop the countdown. While reading other SO posts, I found about clearInterval(), but it seems I am missing something here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Bonus appreciation points will be awarded if someone is kind enough to explain to me why the sample code is not working as expected.

```
    import React from "react";

    export default class TestInterval extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                countDown: this.props.countDown, // An integer from father component
            }
        }

        timer = () => {
            setInterval(() => {
                if (this.state.countDown === 0) {
                    this.stopCountDown();
                }
                this.setState( prevState => ({
                    countDown: prevState.countDown - 1, 
                }));
            }, 1000)
        }

        startCountDown = () => {
            this.timer();
        }

        stopCountDown = () => {
            clearInterval(this.timer); // Not working
        }

        render () {
            return (
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.startCountDown}>
                        Start Countdown
                    </button>
                    <p>{this.state.countDown}</p>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question has actually nothing to do with React. It's about vanilla Javascript.

Comment: actually it has something to do with react as the condition the OP checks is in the wrong place, react's life cycle wise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to store the interval reference returned from `setInterval`.
From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval):

> It returns an interval ID which uniquely identifies the interval, so
>   you can remove it later by calling clearInterval().

So your code should look like that for example:

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => {...
```

and then clear it:

```
 clearInterval(this.interval);
```

I would check the condition after the state has truly set (`setState` is asynchronous) you can do it inside the callback of `setState`.

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        countDown: prevState.countDown - 1,
      }), () => {
        if (this.state.countDown === 0) {
          this.stopCountDown();
        }
      });
    }, 1000)
```

Running example:

```js
class TestInterval extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      countDown: this.props.countDown, // An integer from father component
    }
  }

  timer = () => {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        countDown: prevState.countDown - 1,
      }), () => {
        if (this.state.countDown === 0) {
          this.stopCountDown();
        }
      });
    }, 1000)
  }

  startCountDown = () => {
    this.timer();
  }

  stopCountDown = () => {
    clearInterval(this.interval); // Not working
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.startCountDown}>
          Start Countdown
                    </button>
        <p>{this.state.countDown}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TestInterval countDown={3} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```