# Trying to make a loader! error: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a simple loader in react native and it gives me this error

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a
> no-op, but it indicates a `memory leak` in your application. To fix,
> cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the
> `componentWillUnmount` method.

my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import AnimatedLoader from 'react-native-animated-loader';


export default class Loader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { visible: false };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        visible: !this.state.visible
      });
    }, 6000);
  }

  render() {
    const { visible } = this.state;
    return (
        <View backgroundColor={'black'} style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent:'center' }}>
      <AnimatedLoader
        visible={visible}
        overlayColor="white"
        source={require("./loader.json")}
        animationStyle={styles.lottie}
        speed={1}
      >
        <Text>Doing something...</Text>
      </AnimatedLoader>
      </View>
    );
  }
  
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  lottie: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  }
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47254163/5385381

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only guess is that the component is unmounting before the timeout expires. Save a reference to the timer and clear it when the component is unmounting.

```
timerId = null;

componentDidMount() {
  this.timerId = setInterval(() => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      visible: !prevState.visible
    }));
  }, 6000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearTimeout(this.timerId);
}
```